# Show attribute of form object via logger in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to debug my application and check what values are submitted on the form object in my controller class via logger ? How can it be done? Is there any better practice to debug rails application?

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html

Answer (score 1):

Your rails log (eg `log/development.log`) should already show everything that the form submitted, in the "Parameters".  It will look like this:

```
Processing MusicServiceAdmin::UsersController#edit (for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-31 10:34:16) [GET]
  Session ID: 3c0cfbe7ff23f8f718f6626748a4a
  Parameters: {"id"=>"35363"}
```

Comment: thanks for the help !! can you tell the syntax in case i want to get the value of submitted form object on the console in the controller.rb file ?

Comment: `Rails.logger.debug "params[:foo] = #{params[:foo]}"`?  Not sure if this is what you mean by "value of submitted form object".

Answer (score 0):

**Params**

**Each request** in Rails is tracked using the `console` - you should examine the `params` which come through from there:

```
Started POST "/admin/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-26 16:25:34 +0100
Processing by Admin::Users::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"+I1TKfc1YDuil7EI1frrFIoerNg5uonB1CIiujJO0jo=", "user"=>{"email"=>"*********", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign In"}
  [1m[36mUser Load (482.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`email` = 'rpeck@frontlineutilities.co.uk'  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35m (435.0ms)[0m  BEGIN
  [1m[36mSQL (439.0ms)[0m  [1mUPDATE `users` SET `current_sign_in_at` = '2014-04-26 15:25:35', `last_sign_in_at` = '2014-04-04 12:08:45', `sign_in_count` = 51, `updated_at` = '2014-04-26 15:25:36' WHERE `users`.`id` = 2[0m
  [1m[35m (448.0ms)[0m  COMMIT
  [1m[36mOption Load (404.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  `options`.* FROM `options`  WHERE `options`.`name` = 'site_robots' LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mOption Load (357.0ms)[0m  SELECT  `options`.* FROM `options`  WHERE `options`.`name` = 'site_title' LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mOption Load (428.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  `options`.* FROM `options`  WHERE `options`.`name` = 'site_description' LIMIT 1[0m
Redirected to http://lvh.me:3000/****
Completed 302 Found in 3165ms (ActiveRecord: 2993.2ms)
```

If you want to "debug", you just have to examine the various params / actions which are rendered in the console. Alternatively, you may also wish to the use the `Rails.logger.info` method for specific data:

```
#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
Class YourController < ApplicationController
   def index
      Rails.logger.info("Test")
   end
end
```